# Adding additional class field throws flowtype error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to follow the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to call a function every x seconds like so :

```
componentDidMount () {
  const { dispatch, match } = this.props
  dispatch(loadPipelineExecutions(match.params.pipelineId))
  this.reloadExecutions = setInterval(
    () => dispatch(loadPipelineExecutions(match.params.pipelineId)),
    3000
  )
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  clearInterval(this.reloadExecutions)
}
```

But I'm getting a flowtype error saying : Cannot assign `setInterval(...)` to `this.reloadExecutions` because property `reloadExecutions` is missing in `TableExecutionsContainer`.

Is it a normal flow behavior ?

Comment: Have you tried to do it this way? `this['reloadExecutions'] = setInterval(` it should set new property in your object

Comment: This is not working